# Broom::augment() : Is there any way to customize column names or specify output columns?

Tags: r, broom

I want to augment the data frame with `.fitted` columns from `broom::augment()` for different `lm()` models so that I can compare the predictions later.  I (re)name() the `.fitted` column for each model, but `augment()` also adds `.rownames` `.se.fit`, etc., columns.  So when I run `augment()` for the second model I get

> Error: Column `.rownames` must have a unique name

for each of the columns from `augment()` that I am not interested in.

I end up un-selecting each of the columns from `augment()` that I am not interested in.  I have to do this after each call to `augment()`.

```
{r}
require(tidyverse)
require(broom)
require(ISLR)

lm.obj <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
Auto <- Auto %>% 
  augment(x = lm.obj) %>% 
  rename(mpg_pred_linear = .fitted)

qd.obj <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower + I(horsepower^2), Auto)
Auto <- Auto %>% 
  augment(x = qd.obj) %>% 
  rename(mpg_pred_quad = .fitted)
```

I know I could use `predict.lm()` instead, but in the course I am teaching I have already used `augment()` to create the predictions, and I wanted consistency for my students.

Are there options in `augment.lm()` that I am not finding that allow for customization of column names? Or choice of output columns?

I am not sure if this is a problem I just need to cope with, or if I should submit it as an issue instead.  Please advise (or chastise) as you see fit.

Comment: Are you sure you want the predictions in wide format rather than long format, which would be easier (and could be spread if necessary)?

Comment: To clarify: is your general goal is to attach only the fitted values for a linear and quadratic trend to the current dataset (at least, in this example)? And to do so in a way your students will understand :)?

Comment: Richard, I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Andrew, the goal is to have columns for the fitted values for linear, quadratic, and other models for both the training and test sets.  The ultimate goal is to calculate (by hand, i.e., using R and formulas) the MSE for each model to illustrate using the MSE for model selection and to illustrate that training error is less than test error.  This is part of a lecture to motivate LOOCV, k-fold CV, and bootstrap.  I want the students to learn the concepts and code for these three CV methods, and I don't want to muddy the lecture with new code only used for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `rename_at()`, with the function `start_with()` in order to identify all the columns you just added with `augment()` and to rename all of them:

```
lm.obj <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
iris <- iris %>% 
  augment(x = lm.obj) %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('.')), funs(paste0('mod1', .)))

colnames(iris)
#  [1] "Sepal.Length"   "Sepal.Width"    "Petal.Length"   "Petal.Width"    "Species"        "mod1.fitted"    "mod1.se.fit"   
#  [8] "mod1.resid"     "mod1.hat"       "mod1.sigma"     "mod1.cooksd"    "mod1.std.resid"
```

This way you can iterate several times :

```
qd.obj <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Species + I(Petal.Length^2), iris)
iris <- iris %>% 
  augment(x = qd.obj) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('.')), funs(paste0('mod2', .)))
```

Comment: Of course, rename_at().  It is the same length as the code I had.  Thanks.
I actually use augment(x = lm.obj, newdata = iris) to reduce the number of cols that augment() returns.  With rename, I can keep them all, named by model.  Thanks.